# phonegap single sign on

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, single-sign-on

I'm building a PhoneGap app where one of the requirements is to support SSO (Single Sign On).

I have a web application which supports different types of authentication. Now I'm building a mobile application (using PhoneGap) for the same web application and want to use the same authentication method to log-in from mobile which I use for logging-in from the web application

Basically the PhoneGap mobile app should use the same authentication method (say Customer Portal/SAML/NT Auth etc) which the user uses to  log-in into the web application from a desktop

The main problem I'm facing is, if the web application is configured to use Customer Portal for authentication, then the user should be redirected to the portal and after authentication he should be redirected back to the mobile (PhoneGap) application and should get a authentication token which can be used by the mobile app for further requests.

I was trying to use the InAppBrowser/ChildBrowser plugin to open the external URL (customer portal) and post data (authentication token) from InAppBrowser to the PhoneGap mobile app but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or even if it is feasible.

Please can somebody help me in if the above approach is feasible or is there any other approach I have to take.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found the solution?